# I want to load two welcome files in web.xml for two different url pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>apiServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/api-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/web-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/admin-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>apiServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/resources/web/views/layout/layout.html</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Now I want to load welcome file like this

```
  1. Welcome file- <welcome-file>/resources/web/views/layout/layout.html</welcome-file>
     Url Pattern- <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

  2. Welcome file- <welcome-file>resources/admin/views/layout/layout.html</welcome-file> 
     Url Pattern- <url-pattern>admin/*</url-pattern>
```

I want to load welcome file from the web.xml only not from the controller. I tried few approach to load different welcome file for different url pattern from web.xml but its not working :(

Thanks

Comment: Create some kind of controller like `WelcomeController` and map your request patterns to the methods and return the respective view based on the pattern. Instead of using Welcome files and making life complecated

Comment: ok, I will try to handle it by controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlrewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for passing to your welcome file without user noticing it. It is simple and usefull.

```
<rule>
  <from>/</from>
  <to>/layout.html</to>
</rule>

<rule>
  <from>/admin/</from>
  <to>/admin_layout.html</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I had the same issue, if you have different welcome pages for different directories you have to seperate as 2 projects and deploy it as seperated webapps OR you can use URL rewrite which is more usefull. It solved my situation I hope it solves yours.